# Spark Structured Streaming exception handling

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I reading data from a MQTT streaming source with Spark Structured Streaming API.

```
val lines:= spark.readStream
  .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
  .option("topic", "Employee")
  .option("username", "username")
  .option("password", "passwork")
  .option("clientId", "employee11")
  .load("tcp://localhost:8000").as[(String, Timestamp)]
```

I convert the streaming data to case class Employee

```
case class Employee(Name: String, Department: String)    
val ds = lines.map {
        row =>
          implicit val format = DefaultFormats
          parse(row._1).extract[Employee]
      }
  ....some transformations
 df.writeStream
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("es")
        .option("es.resource", "spark/employee")
        .option("es.nodes", "localhost")
        .option("es.port", 9200)
        .start()
        .awaitTermination()
```

Now there were some messages in the queue which had different structure than `Employee` case class. Lets say some required columns were missing. My streaming job failed with field not found exception.

Now I will like to handle such exception and also will like to send an alert notification for the same. I tried putting a try/catch block.

```
case class ErrorMessage(row: String)        
catch {

      case e: Exception =>
        val ds = lines.map {
          row =>
            implicit val format = DefaultFormats
            parse(row._1).extract[ErrorMessage]
        }
        val error = lines.foreach(row => {
          sendErrorMail(row._1)
        })
    }
  }
```

Got the exception that `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
mqtt`

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should rather use the return object of the `start()` method as described in [Spark streaming doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#managing-streaming-queries). Something like:

```
val query = df.writeStream. ... .start()
try {
   //If the query has terminated with an exception, then the exception will be thrown.
   query.awaitTermination()
catch {
   case ex: Exception => /*code to send mail*/
}
```

Implementing your own foreach sink can cause overhead with frequent opening and closing connections.

Answer (score 0):

I created a foreach sink in the catch block and was able to handle the exceptions and send out mail alerts as well.

```
catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      val foreachWriter = new ForeachWriter[Row] {
        override def open(partitionId: Timestamp, version: Timestamp): Boolean = {
          true
        }

        override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
         code for sending mail.........
        }

        override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
      }
      val df = lines.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json")
      df.writeStream
        .foreach(foreachWriter)
        .outputMode("append")
        .start()
        .awaitTermination()
  }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused with the solution. You have two queries. whenever there is a failure in the first query, how is the second writeStream handling it. COuld you help explain. I'm right now, having a similar problem with my logic in a ForeachWriter writing to Solr (I'm not using the spark-solr library) using solrJ. The job fails when a field in the input stream is wrong but I'm trying to understand on how to handle without he checkout advancing

Answer (score 0):

If the streaming is writing to delta tables you may use the merge for handling exceptions.
First, create the function tho merge and handle problems.

```
from delta.tables import DeltaTable

myTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "MYTABLE")

# Function to upsert microBatchOutputDF into Delta table using merge
def insertMessages(microBatchOutputDF, batchId):
    try:
        myTable.alias("trg").merge(
            microBatchOutputDF.alias("src"),
            """
            src.keyId = trg.keyId and 
            src.secondKeyId = trg.secondKeyId
            """) \
        .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
        .execute()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception in writing data to MYTABLE: {e}")
        try:
            pass # do something with the bad data / log the issue
        except:
            print(f"Exception in writing bad data / logging the issue: {e}")
```

Run the stream:

```
mytable_df.writeStream.format("delta").foreachBatch(insertMessages).outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/delta/messages/_checkpoints2/").start()
```

Important note:
If at least one record in the batch causes an exception (for example NOT NULL constraint) then the whole batch (all records) are not merged. The stream keep working after that issue, it's not breaking.